# HXT: How to stop processing after the first successful transformation?

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm trying to use [Control.Arrow.ArrowTree](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.2.2/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#t%3aArrowTree) to build a HTML processing arrow that stops after the first successful transformation (depth-first) in the given tree. I.e. a function with the type

```
processFirst :: (ArrowTree a, Tree t) => a (t b) (t b) -> a (t b) (t b)
```

For example, to add the class "first" to the very first list item in a HTML document, one could build the arrow

```
processFirst (hasName "li" `guards` addAttr "class" "first")
```

I'm rather new to HXT and I've been reading the API docs for a couple of hours now and trying to figure out how to implement `processFirst`, but I haven't been able to fit all the pieces together. `processTopDownUntil` sounded promising at first, but that function only stops the processing for a particular sub-tree, so it will still transform all elements excluding nested ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood the question, but I'll try to answer :)

Lets try the next:

```
test = flip runLA undefined $ xshow $
  constA "<xml><x>X1</x><x>X2</x></xml>" >>> xread
  >>> processFirst (hasName "x" `guards` addAttr "class" "first")

processFirst f = f `orElse` processChildren (processFirst f)
```

The definition of `processFirst` is the same as definition of `processTopDownUntil`. This function will output something like:

```
["<xml><x class=\"first\">X1</x><x class=\"first\">X2</x></xml>"]
```

The problem should be clear -- if `f` fails for the top node, then `processFirst` will be called for every child. We need a way to abort processing of the other children if `f` succeeded on some child.

Possible solution could be to use state arrow:

```
processFirst f = fromSLA False process
  where
  process = (getState >>> isA not)
            `guards`
            (f >>> changeState (const $ const True))
            `orElse`
            processChildren process
```

The idea is to set state when `f` succeeded and check it before processing.

Note: now `f` should be `SLA` arrow. If it is not what you want, the you can try to collect all children (using e.g. `listA`) and process them purely.

So, the solution is not ideal, but I hope it will help you as a starting point.